# Entity Framework timeout error due to database block

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2005

Have a project that uses the entity framework (v1 with .NET 3.5). It's been in use for a few years, but it's now being used by more people. Started getting timeout errors and have tracked it down to a few things. For simplicity sake let's say my database has three tables, product, part, and product_part. There are ~1400 parts and a handful of products.

The user has the ability to add any number of parts to a product. My problem is that when there are many parts added to the product the inserts take a long time. I think it's mostly due to network traffic/delay, but to insert all 1400 takes around a minute. If someone goes in and tries to view the details of a part while those records are being inserted I get a timeout and can see a block in the Activity Monitor of SQL Server.

What can I do to avoid this? My apologies if this has been asked before and I missed it.

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the root problem is that your write transaction is taking so long. EF is not good at executing mass DML. It executes each insert in a separate network roundtrip and separate statement.

If you want to insert 1400 rows, and performance matters, do the insert in one single statement using TVP's (`INSERT ... SELECT * FROM @tvp`). Or switch to bulk-copy but I don't think that will be advantageous at only 1400 rows.

If your read transactions are getting blocked, and this is a problem, switch on snapshot isolation. That takes care of the readers 100% as they never block under snapshot isolation.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. I hadn't heard of TVPs, but turns out I can't use them because the client uses 2005. They're upgrading next year. I'll have to talk to their DBA about turning on snapshot isolation, but for now I'm going to go the bulk insert route. It feels a bit like driving a small nail with a sledge hammer. I'm using this - http://elegantcode.com/2012/01/26/sqlbulkcopy-for-generic-listt-useful-for-entity-framework-nhibernate/

Comment: Dumb follow up question. If I run 1400 insert statements in Management Studio does that lock the table? Why the difference?

Comment: It doesn't lock the table, it locks the individual rows. In both cases! No difference there. SSMS is a client just like your app is.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I asked is that I sent 8000 insert statements through SSMS and was able to view records (in my app) unlike when I send a lot of inserts through my app.

Comment: With 8k inserts per transaction you probably hit lock escalation (triggering at 5k I think). Try slapping `WITH (ROWLOCK)` onto the inserts or disable lock escalation for the session.